# Multi Instance Apps and Azure Authentication Best Practices

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We have a multi-instance Saas Application:

- Each of our clients is given their own instance and their own subdomain for the site.
- Our application (Web app & API) is protected by Azure, currently with the ADAL javascript libraries
- We also have a second API for system-level integration that needs to be protected, currently using a second 'native' azure app, but this is likely incorrect and we want to consolidate
- Our application reads and writes to the Azure AD both through the AzureAD Graph API and Microsoft Graph API (including password reset calls)

We're looking at Azure AD application configuration options and want to make sure we're building the most sensible and secure Azure AD Application. Here are some of the documentation we've been looking at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare

We want the application to be multi-tenant to ease configuration, and allow availability in the Gallery; but when looking into doing so we're left with some security questions.

**A. Which application version to use**

- 1) v1. Allows access to both Graph API. And as suggested by Microsoft we should use this when we're not concerned with Microsoft Accounts.
- 2) v2. When looking at the MS Graph API documentation it recommends using v2. Reportedly doesn't work for AzureAD Graph API? Allows the same app to be of multiple types (Web App/API and native), which we may or may not need to protect both our web api and our system api (which we're still trying to model).

**B. How to manage the reply URL when our clients have different sub-domains?**

I've noted the following options:

- 1) On the app registry, we add the reply urls for all of our customers. This seems okay because we only need to do it once, but feels odd. Is there a limit to the number of reply urls?
- 2) Have one reply url, but manage an external tool to route the responses to the correct instance, leveraging the state url parameter. Microsoft seems to be suggesting that in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authenticate  I'm not sure if ADAL allows us to set the state for a return subdomain url though. Is this approach common?
- 3) Is it possible for each ServiceProvider instance in our client's directories to configure the reply url to their own subdomain? I feel like this would be the cleanest approach, but I don't see documentation for it. It would be nice if we could set the replyURL programmatically as well.

**C. How to manage authorization to the Graph APIs (AzureAD and Microsoft Graph)**

I've noted the following options:

- 1) Use the client credential flow, with a single application key (used for all clients). As clients subscribe they will admin consent with our app to give the application permission to their directory. Of course we'd do our best to keep that key secure. But if for some reason it was compromised this would put all of our clients at risk, not just the one instance that was compromised.
- 2) Same as 1, but use a certificate instead of a secret key. I understand this could be a little more secure, but I don't see how it wouldn't suffer from the same issue as 1.
- 3) Instead of using application permissions, use delegated permissions with an admin user. This would be good, in that it inherently prevents one instance of our app from talking to the wrong directory. However changes to the administrator may interrupt service; and I think it is best audit-wise that our application is responsible for the changes it makes. (Also, do delegated permissions allow for password resetting? I know for app permissions you need to run powershell script to upgrade the application's directory role)
- 4) Is there some way for the service principal to generate a unique key for it's directory on creation? can this be handed back to our app programmatically? Perhaps during admin consent?

Answer (score 1):

Really good questions. I'll try to answer each to the best of my knowledge, but if someone has other ideas, feel free to comment/add your own answer.

> A. Which application version to use

v2 should allow you to call Azure AD Graph API. The documentation you linked shows an example of specifying Azure AD Graph scopes:

> GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=2d4d11a2-f814-46a7-890a-274a72a7309e&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fdirectory.read%20https%3A%2F2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fdirectory.write

The main decision point if you should use v2 is: **Do you need to support Microsoft accounts which are not in an Azure AD?** If yes, you need to use v2. Otherwise there is no problem using v1 (well, lack of dynamic permissions).

Since you are using Azure AD Graph to modify things, I'm going to guess pure Microsoft accounts will not work for you. **I would recommend sticking with v1.**

v2 also has some limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations

> B. How to manage the reply URL when our clients have different sub-domains?

I could not find documentation on a limit for URLs. It could be that you can add however many you want. But I am not sure :)

If your subdomains look like this: `https://customer.product.com`, you can configure the reply URL as:

```
https://*.product.com
```

It will then allow any subdomain to be specified in the `redirect_uri`.

Though note that at the time of writing this, **wildcard reply URLs are not supported in v2**.

> C. How to manage authorization to the Graph APIs (AzureAD and Microsoft Graph)

Using multiple keys makes no sense as they are all equal anyway :) Any of them could be used to call another tenant.

You can store the secret/certificate in an Azure Key Vault, and then use [Azure AD Managed Service Identity](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-managed-service-identity) to get it on app startup.

I would prefer using delegated permissions, but if the users of the app won't have the rights to do the things your app needs to do then that does not work.

I would just make sure it is not possible for a customer's instance to call to the APIs with another tenant id. And also make sure token caches are separated in such a way that it is not possible to get another tenant's access token (an in-memory cache on the instance would be good).

Comment: B is particularly helpful thank you.
our users only make changes to the directory indirectly. but yes, if we did use delegated permissions then I wouldn't be worried about tenants getting other tenants access tokens.

Comment: that being, if we did use delegated permissions we'd likely just use the same user for all operations. That said do delegated permissions allow password reset? a quick look here looks like it may not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes

Comment: Ahh, you want to do a password reset to a user through your app? It is possible with delegated permissions, specifically the permission which allows the app to act as the signed in user.

Comment: Actually there is no application-level (non-delegated) permission that would allow password resets. Only way is to give the service principal a super-privileged role manually :)

Comment: Yes we currently configure the app to call password reset by running a powershell script to give the Company Administrator role to the service principal. So maybe it would make more sense to go the delegated permissions route, just to save that configuration step?

Comment: It would be safer also. Try and see if the delegated approach works :)

Comment: @juunas  V2 Endpoint doesn't support wildcard reply urls. Please correct me if it's incorrect. Can you please recommend a way to handle this in v2 endpoint? I have tried the new app registration portal, manually updating the manifest with an wildcard url - it doesn't accept it.

Comment: You are correct :) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-redirect-uris does not say it explicitly but it certainly does not allow them. At least not yet. I'll add an edit mentioning that, thanks!